# How can I addforce to an object in the global axes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sphere in a 2.5D game. I want to add force after the sphere is launched but to the right only. The problem is that when I `rb.AddForce(transform.right * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);` it applies the force to the axes of the sphere that have changed after the rotation and so the sphere launches to the sky. Is there a way to fix this without the use of rotation constraints?(using C#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Vector3.right` which is basicly `Vector3(1, 0, 0)`.

```
rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html